# How to insert (...) in middle of the string if it exceed over 100

Tags: jquery, html

```
//string values can be changed
var str1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";
var str2 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the industry";

//Constant string values
var name1 = "Ramesh";
var name2 = "suresh";
var name3 = "Raj";
```

I have five string variables in that two variables can be changed at any time, remaining three variables are constant. Now i want calculate the length of the **five variables** if it exceeds 100 then in the str1 , str2 string i want to insert (...) in the middle of the string. If it is less then 100 nothing should happen
Note: After appending (...) again the total length of the Five string should not exceeds 100

```
// this is code what i am having

$(".clickme").click(function(){
       var len = str1.length + str1.length + name1.length + name2.length + name3.length;
        if( len > 100 )
        {
            str1mid = str1.length / 2;
            str2mid = str2.length / 2;
            if(str1mid > 50)
            {
              str1mid = 50;
            }
            if(str2mid > 50)
            {
              str2mid = 50;
            }
            str1 = str1.substring(0,str1mid) + '...' + str1.substring(str1mid,100);
            str2 = str2.substring(0,str2mid) + '...' + str2.substring(str2mid,100);
            console.log(str1);
            console.log(str2);          
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(" Yes it is less then 100");
        }

   alert(len);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code to share (even if it doesn't currently work)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like that:

```
if(str1.length > 100)
{
   var middle = str1.length/2;
   str1 = str1.substring(0,middle) + '...' + str1.substring(middle);
}
```

You can use `str1.substring(0,100)` to trunc your max of 100 caracters

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean to shorten the string and add the ... to the end. Here is a function that will do that.

```
function shorten(text) {
  if (text.length > 100) {
    return text.substring(0,97)+"...";
  } else {
    return text;
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var str1 = shorten("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry");
```

Comment: Be careful defining functions like this. If you use `function foo() {}`, you can call it anywhere. If you use `var foo = function(){}`, you can only call it after the definition.

Comment: Also this will result in a string of length 103. The ellipsis adds 3 characters to the length.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes it seem like you want one thing, however your example code looks like you want something else. The first function is what your question makes it sound like you want, the second is what the your example code seems to indicate.

Function 1:

```
function capLength(str1, str2, name1, name2, name3) { 
  // Join the strings and get the resulting length.
  // (This is the same as str1 + str2... just marginally faster.)
  var totalLength = [str1, str2, name1, name2, name3].join("").length;

  var excessLength = totalLength - 100;
  if (excessLength <= 0) {
    return; // If the string isn't too long, no changes are needed.
  }

  // Available length for the variable strings (combined) will be
  // 100 - combined length of the constant strings.
  // To get the length of each one, we divide by two.
  var str1Length = (100 - name1.length - name2.length - name3.length) / 2;
  var str2Length = (100 - name1.length - name2.length - name3.length) / 2;

  // It's possible that one string will be under the limit and one will be over.
  // Move the available length from one to the other
  while (str1Length > str1.length) {
    str1Length--;
    str2Length++;
  }
  while (str2Length > str2.length) {
    str2Length--;
    str1Length++;
  }

  str1 = str1.substring(0, str1Length - 3) + "...";
  str2 = str2.substring(0, str2Length - 3) + "...";

  return [str1, str2, name1, name2, name3];
}
```

Function 2:

```
function capLength(str1, str2, name1, name2, name3) { 
  // Join the strings and get the resulting length.
  // (This is the same as str1 + str2... just marginally faster.)
  var totalLength = [str1, str2, name1, name2, name3].join("").length;

  var excessLength = totalLength - 100;
  if (excessLength <= 0) {
    return; // If the string isn't too long, no changes are needed.
  }

  // Available length for the variable strings (combined) will be
  // 100 - combined length of the constant strings.
  // To get the length of each one, we divide by two.
  var str1Length = (100 - name1.length - name2.length - name3.length) / 2;
  var str2Length = (100 - name1.length - name2.length - name3.length) / 2;

  // It's possible that one string will be under the limit and one will be over.
  // Move the available length from one to the other
  while (str1Length > str1.length) {
    str1Length--;
    str2Length++;
  }
  while (str2Length > str2.length) {
    str2Length--;
    str1Length++;
  }

  var str1Mid = str1.length / 2;
  var str2Mid = str2.length / 2;

  if (str1.length != str1Length) {
    str1 = (str1.substring(0, str1.length / 2) + "...").substring(0, str1Length);
  }
  if (str2.length != str2Length) {
    str1 = (str2.substring(0, str2.length / 2) + "...").substring(0, str2Length);
  }

  return [str1, str2, name1, name2, name3];
}
```